# Write content to uploaded file

Tags: java, iostream

I am reading xlsx file and want to write it on my server. I am getting file name and writing the file content in temporary directory.

When i execute the project. It created file on my server and writes `1kb` content in it. But when I open it it says `file format or file extention` is not valid.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile")
public String uploadFileHandler(@ModelAttribute UploadFile uploadFile,
        @RequestParam("filename") String name
      /*  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file*/) {

    if (!name.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = name.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();             

            return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name
                + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

jsp:

js:

```
function uploadTemplate()
    {
        var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value;
        document.uploadRequest.action = "uploadFile?filename="+filename;
        document.uploadRequest.submit();
    }
```

html:

```
<form:form action="" method="POST" modelAttribute="uploadFile" name="uploadRequest"  enctype="multipart/form-data">     
            <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <button onClick = "downloadTemplate()"  style="width:250px" type="submit" class="admin_search_btn"><spring:message code="lblDownloadXls"></spring:message></button>
            </div>
            <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >                  
                <form:input path="fileName" style="width:200px" id="filename" class="admin_search_btn" type="file" />
                 <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" > 
                    <button onClick = "uploadTemplate()" type="submit" class="admin_search_btn"><spring:message code="lblSubmit"></spring:message></button>&nbsp;
                    <button  type="submit" class="admin_search_btn">Cancel</button>
                </div>          

            </div>                      
        </form:form>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to write "name" parameter instead of the content. Is it what you are trying to do?
Can you also give example of filename param value?

Comment: @Maas: I added the jsp content

Comment: But you are writing the bytes :  byte[] bytes = name.getBytes();

That isn't content of the updated file. <br> What you should do is create another File for the filename and read the content of it.

Comment: @Maas: If I created another file name then also i need to write in it. What content should I write there?

Comment: @user123 are you using `Struts`

Answer (score 0):

Ok Now that I am understanding your question to some extent, here is my answer

You are trying to write the uploaded file (uploadFile) into your server with the name filename.

Change your like this.

```
 if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            try {


    **// Here read the content of uploadFile (not of the name)**
                byte[] bytes = name.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));

**// Write the content of the uploadfile not the filename**
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();             

                return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }
```